# Align elements at the same line (stretch out the entire layout dynamically)

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4, alignment

I'm using MVC 4 layout view (html, css).

I would like to do a menu bar that has 6 elements at the same line. However I do not want to fix the width for each element just to ensure they align properly. The reason is that I wanted to control the menu bar with codes as menu items will be hide from the unauthorized users.

How can it be done? Please help as I'm really new in this.

Here's the example. For user A (can see 5 items on the menu bar). All 5 items arrange nicely on the page.
[image]

For user B (can see only 4 items on the menu bar). All 4 items will also arrange nicely on the page.
[image]

I mean the entire page width. I do not want the element to stick closely to each other while leaving empty spaces at the back.

Your help is much appreciated! Thanks! :D

Comment: So, you want to know how to create a horizontal menu?

Comment: You would do this with proper CSS styling. [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_float5)

Comment: @SaladinAkara yes horizontal menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and most common way of doing this is through the use of an unordered list, with CSS applied to it. Something like this will do what you want:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Menu item 1</li>
    <li>Menu item 2</li>
    <li>Menu item 3</li>
    <li>Menu item 4</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul
{
    list-style-type: none; /* removes the bullet points */
}

ul li
{
    display: block; /* makes each item a 'box' */
    float: left; /* makes them stay on the same line */
}
```

Additional styling will be needed to remove margins and padding from the list, and you will need to apply classes to your list as the CSS above will apply to *all* unordered lists.

But this should put you in the right direction.

**UPDATE:**

From [this site](http://www.darkstardesign.com/darkstar-blog/2012/11/27/stretching-horizontal-navigation-menus-to-the-full-width-of-a-layout/), you can make the menu fill the entire width like so:

```
/* this selector could be div#nav instead of nav depending on which tag you wrapped the ul in */
nav {
display: table;
width: 100%;
border-collapse: collapse;
border: none;
}
nav ul {
display: table-row;
}
nav li {
display: table-cell;
margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But how do I make the align properly? For example if 5 elements each will take 20% of the total page width? If 4 then 25%? Problem is the page will not have a fix number of elements, some 4 some 5 depending on the control.

Comment: I used the code but the menu bar is appearing as vertical menu?

Comment: You'll need to edit the code to ensure it matches your HTML markup. Simply copy-pasting it won't work.

Comment: The updated code is correct, it's what I had prepared ^^
http://jsfiddle.net/tive/deKBG/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want fixed width, try `width:auto;`

And Here is a [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/geovani075/cSyBu/)

Comment: Hi. The width that I'm saying is actually the page width. Let's say the page width is 100%, how do I make the menu bar with elements spread nicely across the page horizontally? Instead of one after another that sticks closely together?